# Printf in Java with variable spaces before the output

Tags: java, printf

With `printf` I can decide how many space characters should be before the variable `i` that I want to print. In the example below, it is 10. Is it possible to have there a variable instead of the number 10? So that the spaces characters depend on the value of a variable?

```java
System.out.printf("%10d" , i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The format string is still a string, so assuming a `width` variable `System.out.printf("%" + width + "d", x);` does the trick.

So for example

```
var width = 10; var x = 123;
System.out.printf("%" + width + "d", x);
```

prints        `123` (7 leading spaces + 3 digits = 10), while

```
var width = 3; var x = 123;
System.out.printf("%" + width + "d", x);
```

prints `123`

Comment: It's annoying that Java didn't adopt "%*d" (etc) from C's printf.

Answer (score 0):

Define a lambda to create the desired width and then call that prior to printing the value.

```
Function<Integer, String> format = width-> "%%%dd\n".formatted(width);
int x = 4567;
System.out.printf(format.apply(10),x); 
System.out.printf(format.apply(5),x);
// or create it once for multiple printf calls.
String form = format.apply(3);
System.out.printf(form, 2);
System.out.printf(form, 4);
```

prints

```
      4567
 4567
  2
  4
```

- `%%%dd` - the first `%` escapes the second so on the last `%d` formats the width value.
- then that format string is returned and used to format the supplied argument in the `printf` statement